# why mapping result is undefined?

Tags: json, mapping, observable, angular5

I'm trying get jSon from server and mapping it to the class in Angular 5 app.
Following is service method that working without errors:

```
getSearchResultTable(hash: number): Observable<Model.SearchResult.RootObject> {

    return this.http.get<Model.SearchResult.RootObject>('http://somelink/api/SearchResult/123')
    .map(res => new Model.SearchResult.RootObject());
    return tmp;
}
```

following comoponent class:

```
export class SearchResultPageComponent implements OnInit {
  searchResult: Model.SearchResult.RootObject;

  constructor(private searchResultService: SearchResultService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchResultService.getSearchResultTable(122).subscribe( data => {
      this.searchResult = data;
    });
    let t = this.searchResult;
  }
}
```

The `Model.SearchResult.RootObject` is an complex object and i generate it by jSon on [following](http://json2ts.com/) service.

In all examples this method is described...but in my case `this.searchResult` is `undefined`. What i'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Also I tried remove `map` and change the service method in a way:

```
getSearchResultTable(hash: number): Model.SearchResult.RootObject {
this.http.get<Model.SearchResult.RootObject>('http://somelink/api/SearchResult/123')
    .subscribe( data => {
        this.searchResult = data;
      });
    return this.searchResult;
}
```

And component method like:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchResult = this.searchResultService.getSearchResultTable(122);
    }
```

Service get next exception:

- ReferenceError: data is not defined
- at eval (eval at SearchResultService.getSearchResultTable (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/search-module/services/search-result.service.ts),
  :1:1)
- at SearchResultService.getSearchResultTable (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/search-module/services/search-result.service.ts:27:21)
- at SearchResultPageComponent.ngOnInit (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/search-module/pages/search-result/search-result.component.ts:23:54)
- at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12291:19)
- at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13794:20)
- at checkAndUpdateNode (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13737:16)
- at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14609:76)
- at debugCheckDirectivesFn (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14550:13)
- at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///SearchModule/SearchResultPageComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9:5)
- at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14535:21)

**UPDATE**

In my case following snippet is correct:

```
this.http.get<Model.SearchResult.RootObject>('http://someurl/api/SearchResult/123')
.subscribe( (data: Model.SearchResult.RootObject) => {
    this.searchResult = data;
  });
return this.searchResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular 5 you don't need to use map you can directly covert your response in json form in the the subscribe method

Comment: Can you share some example?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you by example: 
this is my service(Postman) returning data in json format.
 [image]

Now this my component's method--getdata which is calling the service method

```
getdata() {
    this.apiHelperService.getdata().subscribe(domainres => {
      // this.domain = domainres,
      this.msg = JSON.stringify(domainres);//,  
      // this.availabilty = this.domain.Available
    }
      , error => { this.msg = "Error function: " + error; })

  }
```

Now this is my service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ApiHelperService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getdata( ): Observable<any> {      

        return this._http.get("http://localhost:8080/domain/facebookjhjhj.com")
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

and I am getting the result like this on browser:

[image]

If I comment the `map()` line then then my output is like this.

[image]

Now coming to your question Look at this line, You are not converting res to anything,

```
.map(res => new Model.SearchResult.RootObject());
```

Try this :

```
.map(res => <new Model.SearchResult.RootObject()>response.json());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use Angular5 and similar functionality looks different in it. You can see it in last update of my question.

Comment: the same thing, I also tried to explain you in my answer. This is the same angular 5 application answer. there is no need of map() function in angular 5. You can use, map function that depend on your choice.